# kerberos TGT explanation

Tags: windows, kerberos

Any domain user can retrieve a TGT (kerberos hash) from a Domain Controller.

For example using GetUserSPNs.py (Impacket) you can get TGTs

```
GetUserSPNs.py -request -dc-ip 192.168.15.65 SOMETEST-DC.DOMAINFOO.IT/user1
```

After that you get a kerberos hash which is something like:

```
$krb5tgs$23$*Sys$SOMETEST-DC.DOMAINFOO.IT$http/certa.sometest-dc.domainfoo.it*$6a56322bca56e22885d8cb0.....etc
```

My questions/thoughts are:

1) This `$krb5tgs$23$` tells you that it's a Kerberos 5, etype 23, TGS type...is that right?

2)  `Sys$SOMETEST-DC.DOMAINFOO.IT` That means that `Sys` is the user and `SOMETEST-DC.DOMAINFOO.IT` is the realm.

3) `http/certa.sometest-dc.domainfoo.it` Is this the service name? It is not an URL

What is that actually?

4) In order to crack the kerberos hash, I suppose it all depends on the password strength, am I right?

Would it be possible to say in advance if the password used is a strong one?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting a Kerberos "hash", you're getting a "ticket". The ticket is a fully formed ASN.1 structure that encompasses the users identity and is what is used to represent the user on the remote machine. It contains the principal name, which maps to something on the remote machine, and in Windows environments it includes group membership information.

The ticket is encrypted to the remote machines long term credential, which is often a password. The strength of that password (randomness, length) is what protects the ticket from tampering. If you can guess the password you can mint a fake ticket and the remote service won't know any better.

Comment: thanks I thought it was a krbtgt hash..as stated here https://fluidattacks.com/web/blog/roasting-kerberos/  anyway if I can retrieve the password I can access (maybe) the remote machine through RDP...but apart from that what makes me really mad is http/certa.sometest-dc.domainfoo.it which is not an URL , so what is it?

Comment: It's a Service Principal Name -- SPN. It's of the form {service}/name[@realm]. Kerberos was invented 2 decades before the internet so the concept of a URL means nothing to the protocol itself. The link referring to these as hashes is simply wrong. It's not called a hash. It's a ticket. You can crack the crypto protecting the ticket, which in this case is encryption, using a key derived from a password. The key derivation process includes hashing, but the result is referred to as a key, not a hash.

Comment: thanks..but am I right in saying that if I succeed in cracking the encryption protecting the ticket so gaining a password which in this case it is actually the password associated to sys I'm able to get access to the DC? (sys should belong to admin group...I think)

Comment: The *ticket* key is the password of the *service*. The AS-REP key is the *user* password. If you can crack the *service* key you have the service account, which means you can log in as the service, or mint fake tickets for the service. To steal the *user* password you need to crack the AS-REP key.